# Fuzzy/ Wildccard matching of substring with string

Tags: python, search, match, fuzzy-search

I got a list with of the following streets

```
Fakestr. 1
Fakestr. 2
Fakestr. 3
.....
Fakestr. 11
Fakestr. 12
Fakestr. 13
```

And some other 20k of those. (Want to keep the example small).

Now I got another textfile where a Line could or could not hold a Street and Housnumber combination.

For example:

```
── Fakestreet_2-bla aha blatesttest\n
─ Fakestr._2-blablatesttest\n
Fakestreet 5_2017
── Fakestreet_2-jo-what
500000222 Fakestreet 13 .sdfs
Fakestreet_7
dsd Fakestreet 13 hae
500000 Fakestreet 12-14 d
Fakestreet 1 hey what 249
```

So I tried different approaches using difflib (difflib.get_close_matches, SequenceMatcher), wuzzyfuzzy etc.
Non of it worked as desired.

So far i archived the best results with:

```
import re
matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)12','─ Fakestr._2-blablatesttest\n') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Error. 
--> But thats ok.

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)2','── Fakestreet_2-bla aha blatesttest\n') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result:  Fakestreet 2 
--> Thats ok

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)5','Fakestreet 5_2017') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 5 
--> Thats ok

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)2','── Fakestreet_2-jo-what') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 2
--> Thats ok

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)7','── Fakestreet_7') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 7
--> Thats ok

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)5','500000 Fakestreet 1-5 .sdfs') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 1-5
-->That would be okay i can solve this cases later

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)5','dfsd Fakestreet 5,6 aaf') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 5 
-->Thats ok

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)6','500000222 Fakestreet 5,6 .sdfs') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 5,6 
-->Thats ok

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)14','Fakestreet 1  hey what 249') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 1 hey what 124
--> Thats wrong

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)1','500000222 Fakestreet 12-14 .sdfs') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 12-1 
--> Thats wrong

matchobj = re.search('Fakestr(.*)1','222 Fakestreet 13 .sdfs') 
print(matchobj.group(0))
--> Result: Fakestreet 1 
--> Thats wrong
```

So how can I handle the three later cases? There are (only) some restrictions: house numbers cant be longer then 3 numbers. The Housenumber is mostly right after the Streetname.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to change your `.*` to `.*\d+` or `.*[0-9_.,-]+` if you'll allow some characters other than digits as well.